# Name in ones shoe

Tags: names, shoes

A Rabbi said that his following should put the name of a wicked person in their shoe. Is this something with significance? What’s the purpose? What is the effect? Does it have a source? Is this allowed?

Comment: If you're doing it specifically so the name gets erased as you walk, would that be an issue on Shabbos (not a דבר שאינו מתכון anymore if you want it to happen)?

Comment: Do you mean beyond Purim?

Comment: Per @rosends comment ^^, I think O.C. mentions a minhag to write Haman's name on the bottom of the shoe, so that, literally, when hearing Haman's name on Purim one stamps out the name.

Comment: "A Rabbi said" Do you know which one?

Comment: It was in passing in an article so I forgot the name but I will try to find the name of the Rabbi.